# How to clear the cache in an Intel XDK Android application

Tags: android, html, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I have created an Android app using Intel XDK. The app code is static HTML using `iframe` to import external URL.

My problem is when my app install in mobile, after when I update/new record in the database but not display updated/new data in the mobile app.

How do I clear the cache in the mobile app?

Below is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 filterbox">
    <select id="selectbox" name="" class="form-control input-lg" >
      <option value="page1">Link 01</option>
      <option value="page2">Link 02</option>
      <option value="page3">Link 03</option>
      <option value="page4">Link 04</option>
      <option value="page5">Link 05</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 databox">
    <iframe src="http://www.xxxxxxx.com" class="iframe" id="temp"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used this Clear Cache plugin and working fine.

URL:
https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache.git

Thanks.